# AngularJS - page transition sets ng-view height to 0

Tags: css, angularjs

I use page transition from here http://angular-transitions.mgechev.com/#/view/page2.

Any amination works, but when the animation starts, the `ng-view`'s height is being set to 0 which makes that whole page 'jumps' because the loaded page content increases that height.

Any ideas how to fix it ?

### edit

Here's the link to the .zip demo which demonstrates the problem https://mega.co.nz/#!okciUbxL!lwX-HUe36GdDquJeAMD-RanSc1d1vhUVeewaDstpbbA

Comment: I'm not seeing any jumps on the link you provided. Can you provide a plunker or such of the problem you're facing?

Comment: in the link I provided there is the same situation. After main content container `<div ui-view></div>` (in that link) I put `<div style='clear:both;'>lorem</div>` and I see that div jumps to the top during the animation